# Firebase database resets when tapping on Back button

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have just managed to connect a real-time database from Firebase to an Android app I'm building for introducing a list of items, but now I have some problems.

The problems:

1. The database resets when I leave the Activity by pressing the back button. Is it from the code or is it from the database? (see the code below)
2. I can only add one item in the list. The system neglects all the others, although I can see them in the database. I guess it is related to the code. Can anyone help me with this?

In addition to the questions above, is it possible to add a picture to a ListView from (let's say) the Firebase Storage or any other external source using the same database?

In the FireBase online portal, I have only two options (name and value). The value is the one returned on the phone screen. Would it be possible to introduce the image (or link to image) in the code?

```js
public class Events extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference dref;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events);

        listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        dref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                list.add(value);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "database resets"?  Are the values stored in the database removed?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. The database simply resets

Comment: So you look at the database in the Firebase Console and it is empty?

Comment: That's correct. That happens with a simple tap on Back button

Comment: Do the values from your app ever show in in the [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/)?

Comment: There is nothing in the code you posted that would do that.  Data in a Firebase database is deleted by calls to `removeValue()` or `setValue(null)`.  Search your app code for those operations.

Comment: If not, you likely have security rules that disallow your user to write. If you check your logcat output there should be a message about that, but you can (and should) make it more explicit by handling `onCancelled`: `public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException() }`.

Comment: It's the other way @FrankvanPuffelen. I type values in the console and it appears on the screen. At a certain point, it had a nice behavior, but then I did some changes and it went totally bad

Comment: I have these rules: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

Comment: As Bob just commented: if you have data in the database and it gets deleted, you must have code running somewhere that does that.

Comment: I see his point, but I don't think it applies. The Activity that the back button sends back to is just a plain layout with some icons. So there is nothing like removeValue or setValue(null). So the only code that is more relavant would be the one above, I guess. Actually, now I see that every time it resets, the Console shows an ID and "Hello World"

Comment: And the weird stuff is that the phone shows the first value, but neglects all the others that I add in the Console

Comment: Okay. I clean the project and run and now the database is there, but lost all the other lines. It still shows only the first line, regardless of how many values I add...

Comment: I've **never** seen the Firebase Database autonomously delete data that was showing in the console. It simply doesn't work that way. If you manually added data or made changes, and those were still showing when you reloaded the console, the only way they can be removed/changed if by a user in the console or by code in one of your apps. If you see something different, can you provide instructions how I can reproduce that behavior?

Comment: I know it's hard to believe, but I'm telling you that that's what happened. And I can't actually say what I did that it works now. Compiled couple of times, cleaned the code etc. Maybe figuring it out why it doesn't show the other lines might lead to what caused it. It used to work fine at the beginning,  but then things started to get weird.

Comment: Good to hear that it works now @Physther. If the problem re-occurs, please see if you can find steps that help us reproduce what you have. For now I vote to close this question as "not reproducible".

Answer (score 1):

Well, a more optimized way to show data in a listview(or a recyclerview) using firebase is to use a library called "Firebase UI" : 
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

It's a very popular library also we can call it an official one.Follow the simple steps in the Readme there and you will find it so easy to use.

Regarding the second question about the picture thing, Sure you can do that! You can just put the link of the image in the Firebase dashboard and use a library to link it in the code one of them is called "Picasso" :
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Just follow the instructions there or follow a simple video on youtube or something.